# App crashes on line FBSDKAppLinkResolverBoltsClassFromString

Tags: ios, facebook, swift2, testfairy

I am using Facebook sdk and testfairy sdk in my app. I get below crash only when I enable testfairy sdk otherwise it works fine. Below is crash reason I got from testfairy:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to load class BFTaskCompletionSource. Did you link Bolts.framework?'**

When I run from XCode it crashes app crashes on line **FBSDKAppLinkResolverBoltsClassFromString**

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution already as I saw very few people also facing this issue but didn't get any fix yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I didn't include Bolt.framework which comes with Facebook sdk package. But its weird that I wasn't getting any issues if I was disabling TestFairy. My app was crashing with above error only with combination of testfairy. I included Bolt.framework and now it seems to be fine.

Comment: How is this related to TestFairy? Can you please provide a stacktrace? (I work for TestFairy)

Comment: Well, you can easily reproduce this. Include facebook corekit framework and don't include Bolt.framework with latest Testfairy sdk. However it wasn't giving issues in previous sdk I don't remember exact version number though. I can't paste stacktrace here as its too long. Feel free to email me if you need stacktrack :)

Comment: Can you please email it to support at testfairy.com then? a developer will take a look.